# passing (pointer to UINT8 array) and accessing the array as byte array in java

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, arrays, swig

I use the swig to generated the JNI code that wrapped my c library.

but the JNI function return a long integer (a pointer to uint8 array) in java

How can i use the long integer(a pointer to uint8) to get the data in java?

Have anyone a idea ?

note:
    tmp_buff_get is to get a pointer member in a structure

```
SWIGEXPORT jlong JNICALL
Java_www_example_com_util_object_dataJNI_UTIL_OBJECT_tmp_buff_get(
    JNIEnv *jenv, 
    jclass jcls, 
    jlong jarg1, 
    jobject jarg1_
) 
{
    jlong jresult = 0 ;
    struct _util_object *arg1 = (struct _util_object *) 0 ;
    UINT8 *result = 0 ;

    (void)jenv;
    (void)jcls;
    (void)jarg1_;
    arg1 = *(struct _util_object **)&jarg1; 
    result = (UINT8 *) ((arg1)->tmp_buff);
    *(UINT8 **)&jresult = result; 
    return jresult;    => the poiner to UINT8 is return as a SWIGTYPE_p_UINT8 type in java
}


public class SWIGTYPE_p_UINT8 {
    private transient long swigCPtr;

    protected SWIGTYPE_p_UINT8(long cPtr, @SuppressWarnings("unused") boolean futureUse) {
        swigCPtr = cPtr;
    }

    protected SWIGTYPE_p_UINT8() {
        swigCPtr = 0;
    }

    protected static long getCPtr(SWIGTYPE_p_UINT8 obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not return a `jbyteArray` instead (i.e. use `NewByteArray` and populate it with your data)? Note that a Java byte is signed, since you say that the data you have is a bunch of `UINT8`s.

Comment: It's sounds a good idea, i seems  to modify the swig interface file and map UINT8* as jbyteArray ...

Comment: the all files is Swig generated, and i have to check if have the same case in other .c